# Capture PPS timing signal into PC with minimal latency

Tags: uart, ttl

I am looking for a 20 us wide TTL signal to be ingested into my device so that I can sync my OS to a PPS (pulse per second) with chrony.

I'm currently looking at all the ways to have the signal enter my computer. One of them is GPIB. From searching online, the only adapters/converters for GPIB seem to be USB and RS-232.

Is there any way to convert TTL to GPIB? I know I can convert TTL to USB and 232, but is there any way to cut out the middle steps since I imagine that'll cause delays, degradation, and would probably be better to just to have TTL to USB/232 (which I already found ways).

I even tried finding a way to convert it but I'm not sure how the handshaking and management buses would work (would I even need that)?

From looking online (including here), USB appears to be a bad choice due to the "stack", being slow (due to everything sharing a bus?) and such but I still dont understand why. It seems like itd be fine but apparently not. Currently nothing in my system uses GPIB. I just figured no stone should go unturned.

Comment: GPIB is not a good choice.  To pick a better one you'll need to describe what the TTL signal represents and what you want to do with it.

Comment: For example [GPIB relays ans digital I/O modules](https://www.pickeringtest.com/en-ru/products/other/gpib-switching) from Pickering. And [GPIB digital interface](https://www.icselect.com/gpib_digital_intfc_minibox.html) from ICS.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). GPIB does not sound like a terribly good solution these days, perhaps unless other legacy things in your system already use it. What does this TTL signal carry? Is it some form of UART, some sync signal, what is it? This wildly affects what the solution can be. It can range from a cheap raspberry pi-like device or a microcontroller "ingesting" stuff over its GPIO every once in a while and messaging your whatever over the network, to proper thousand dollar industrial GPIO cards.

Comment: the TTL signal is just a pulse per second thats 20 us wide. I just need some interface into my computer so that I can sync it with Chrony (im using a RHEL computer). From looking online, USB is a bad choice due to the "stack", being slow (due to everything sharing a bus?) and such but I still dont understand why. It seems like itd be fine but apparently not.
Currently nothing in my system uses GPIB. I just figured no stone should go unturned.

Comment: Now that's a spec! Please edit it into the question's body so it's easy for everyone trying to answer your question to see.

Comment: Modern consumer PC's just don't have good low-latency I/O.  They're designed to move lots of data in moderate time, not tiny amounts of data with agility.  If you can find something with still has a local serial port you can probably use a status line with enough effort as an interrupt; that would be a good choice as you'll also want to capture the corresponding sentence from your GPS...  If it doesn't have to be a desktop PC, many embedded Linux systems (even a cheap Raspberry Pi) have more direct I/O.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the design in such a cunning way that you don't have to deal with 20µs pulses entering your PC. If this is used for synchronization, using [Precision Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) might be a way to go; you'd only need to make/obtain _something_ that would "convert" such 1 PPS pulses to this... which might actually be what you're trying to do, I don't know. [Have a link for your inspiration](https://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html).

Comment: Realistically you should research what the standard solutions are for the open source package you want to run, on the hardware you want to run it on.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, my PC has a 232 port (and a MAX232 converts TTL to 232 easily enough), but isnt that "slow?" 232 doesn't have a status line or interrupts from what i've seen however. I fear that the PC might miss the PPS.
At RichardtheSpacecat, my timing device is sending PTP/NTP messages to it, but I want further stability/determinism so that when my computer talks with other devices on the network, we can measure various metrics like how each device is offset from one another (and not just with the NTP which can be found via chronyc sources), propagation delay, etc.

Comment: There's quite a bit of misunderstanding embedded there.  The point of an *interrupt* is that you capture an event.  While serial data streams are slower, you would not be reading one in the critical timing, rather you'd be using a status line to capture that an event has occurred as fast as the kernel is able to deal with that.  And then you should probably read the time message from the GPS via the serial port at its more leisurely pace before the _next_ pulse occurs a second later, so that you know *which* second the pulse corresponds to.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm sure theres a lot of misunderstanding on my end (since I consider myself a rookie). 
So does the Linux Kernel decide which I/O lines are interrupts/statuses? My end end goal is to have the hardware clock of the Linux OS sync to the PPS. My current OS offset is off on average from the NTP by about 10 us and I need to see if adding the PPS  improves that among it adding other testing capabilities.

Comment: A locally interfaced serial port's hardware should support status line interrupts, and a Linux kernel should be able to use them.  It may, however, take some careful Kernel configuration to do better then 10 uS... desktop PC operating systems aren't really designed for fine timing.  If you were measuring something other than the behavior of the PC itself it would be tempting to recommend an entirely external solution with an MCU or fixed logic, but it sounds like it's the PC itself ypou want to measure.  It's possible that your ultimate quest here is not very realistic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thats unfortunately what it seeming like (at least with my rookie knowledge). So for my understanding, does the Kernel code designate that the serial line/event is an interrupt since the serial is just a high/low?
I just want to have the PCs internal clock sync to the PPS so that every second coincides with a new second
So my PC is the PXIe 8840 and I'm using RHEL. I was hoping to use chrony's refclock (since chrony hasnt failed me yet) or LinuxPPS API

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18633322/429063 which recommends the Linux PPS system documented at http://linuxpps.org/doku.php for which the status lines of a truly local serial port are a primary option.  This is enough of a "usage" question and involves PC rather than custom hardware, that I'm tempted to argue it should be migrated to stackoverflow and closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming (by the comments) that you actually want to build *some* NTP server with a 1PPS input, you should perhaps look into a Raspberry Pi with the [rpi_gpio_ntpd](https://vanheusden.com/time/rpi_gpio_ntp/) installed. ([Also available here](https://github.com/flok99/rpi_gpio_ntpd).)

This lets you synchronize the timebase of the RPi to an external source connected via one of the GPIO pins, (AFAIK) directly using GPIO interrupts, which sounds about as good as you can get.

[Someone has also built this with a GPS receiver](https://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-NTP.html), and they do have some real-world data on the rather good level of accuracy you can get with this inexpensive setup.

The only problem left to solve would be level conversion from TTL to 3.3V CMOS input the RPi would accept, but this sounds trivial enough.

---

Another option would be the use of the [Precision Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) (if your NTP server supports this, which isn't unlikely), which uses hardware timestamping in network cards and switches to figure out the latency between two endpoints.

This means your network cards **and** the switch in-between (if present) would have to support this. Do check if your network cards support this, many do not. However those that do support PTP can be still affordable (like those based on i210-**T1**).

But this is a standard off-the-shelf solution that is likely to work.

Comment: So I have an NTP server with a 1 PPS output already. I just need a way to get my device to ingest it. The 1 PPS is a 50 ohm TTL signal which unfortunately cant directly plug into any of my devices. I want the NTP to be the master timing device. From my device's inputs (USB, 232, GPIB, expresscard34), I need to figure out a way to convert the PPS to those formats. I know for the first two I can use a MAX232 or FTDI chip, but GPIB seems to have the best/lowest latency but hardest conversion.

Comment: No, GPIB is not going to have the lowest latency, probably the opposite actually.  To put it another way, whatever interface is tying the GPIB host chip to the processor, you won't do better than using that interface *directly*.  Even if you were going to use existing GPIB hardware, rather than actually speaking GPIB what you'd want to do is just drive SRQ signal and craft a driver which instead of implementing GPIB simply configured the host chip to report that as an interrupt, just as you would with a serial port modem status line.

Comment: In that case, all your remaining options are the RS232 (perhaps the interrupts are handled fast enough? Can one get interrupts off the control lines changing?), PCIe/ExpressCard (You'll likely have to make a custom device for this with an FPGA + software to handle your interrupts. Which sounds like an absolute ton of work, but with some luck it could work?), or perhaps the network (You already have an NTP server. Does it support [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) as well?

Comment: Is there any documentations, study, way to tell the best/lowest latency? Only documentation I could find was this 
https://www.ni.com/en-us/innovations/white-papers/11/instrument-bus-performance---making-sense-of-competing-bus-techn.html
I would use PXIe, but for some reason the PXIe lines in my system arent exposed to the OS. 
Also, is there any way you could explain why USB isnt useful in timing critical elements? I understand that all elements are shared on a bus, and found this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/15736/262004 but the links are dead (sorry for the pseudo scope creep)

Comment: @bchang32 - the reality is that this question isn't answerable without knowing the internal topology of this computer and its interfaces.  Anything such as USB which is *polled* is not going to be truly low latency, for that you need either a direct hardware input (an "interrupt") to the processor itself, or else to trigger a capture event in a hardware timer which can itself be read by the processor with known latency.

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and a GPS module with PPS output. The problem is that Raspberry's oscillator is very low quality. The frequency goes up and down. Chrony tries to compensate this but as a conclusion I would say that this was a waste of time and money.